# Merging multiple different tables records. // Splitting table records in tables

Tags: tables

Context
Lets say we have gatherings for 2 groups red and blue.
They have different subsections red, blue.
In every respective subsections, there is a table with the same information.
Moment (counting numeral), Date,  Type (red or blue), main subject.

I have 2 tables and want to generate a 3rd
Or Have 1 and want to generate 2 others

Desired result start

1 table

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{llll}
Moment & Date & Type & subject\\
  1 &    \now{}    &  RED    &   Pie
  2 &    \now{}    &  BLUE &   Pie         
  3 &    \now{}    &  RED    &   Apple
  4 &    \now{}    &  BLUE &   Apple
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{llll}
Moment & Date & Type & subject\\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

2 tables

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{llll}
Moment & Date & Type & subject\\
  1 &    \now{}    &  RED    &   Pie     
  3 &    \now{}    &  RED    &   Apple
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{llll}
Moment & Date & Type & subject\\
  2 &    \now{}    &  BLUE &   Pie     
  4 &    \now{}    &  BLUE &   Apple
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Desired result end

Desired is that the 1 generates the 2 others after.
Ot that 1 is Generated infront and from the 2 others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Splitting*

I'd suggest to use `pgfplotstable` and start from a text file created with `filecontents`.

`pgfplotstable` has the option `row predicate` which allows you to execute some code at every row. With `\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Type}\of\mytable` you get the value of the column "Type" of the current row into `\pgfplotsretval`.

Then you can use `\ifdefstring` from `etoolbox` package to test that value and set `\pgfplotstableuserowfalse` when you don't want to display that row.

Since you didn't post a complete MWE and I don't know `\now` macro, I've used `\today` from `datetime` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotstableset{
    string type,
    column type=l,
    every head row/.style={
        before row=\toprule,
        after row=\midrule,
    },
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomrule
    },  
}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{mytable.dat}
    Moment  Date  Type  subject
    1     {\today}      RED       Pie
    2     {\today}      BLUE    Pie         
    3     {\today}      RED       Apple
    4     {\today}      BLUE    Apple
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread{mytable.dat}{\mytable}

Whole table:\bigskip

\pgfplotstabletypeset{\mytable}

\bigskip\bigskip Table with only rows with column ``Type''=BLUE:\bigskip

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    row predicate/.code={%
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Type}\of\mytable%
        \ifdefstring{\pgfplotsretval}{BLUE}{}{\pgfplotstableuserowfalse}%
    },
    ]{\mytable}

\bigskip\bigskip Table with only rows with column ``Type''=RED:\bigskip

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    row predicate/.code={%
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Type}\of\mytable%
        \ifdefstring{\pgfplotsretval}{RED}{}{\pgfplotstableuserowfalse}%
    },
    ]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Merging*

It's even easier. You can create two text files with `filecontents`, one with the "blue" rows and one with the "red" ones, you can typeset them separately and you can merge them with `\pgfplotstablevertcat`, sorting them, if needed, with `\pgfplotstablesort`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotstableset{
    string type,
    column type=l,
    every head row/.style={
        before row=\toprule,
        after row=\midrule,
    },
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomrule
    },  
}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{mytableblue.dat}
    Moment  Date  Type  subject
    2     {\today}      BLUE    Pie         
    4     {\today}      BLUE    Apple
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mytablered.dat}
    Moment  Date  Type  subject
    1     {\today}      RED       Pie
    3     {\today}      RED       Apple
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread{mytableblue.dat}{\mytable}
\pgfplotstableread{mytableblue.dat}{\mytableblue}
\pgfplotstableread{mytablered.dat}{\mytablered}

Whole table:\bigskip

\pgfplotstablevertcat{\mytable}{\mytablered}
\pgfplotstablesort[sort key={Moment}]\mytable\mytable
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\mytable}

\bigskip\bigskip Table with only rows with column ``Type''=BLUE:\bigskip

\pgfplotstabletypeset{\mytableblue}

\bigskip\bigskip Table with only rows with column ``Type''=RED:\bigskip

\pgfplotstabletypeset{\mytablered}

\end{document}
```

The result is the same as before.

Comment: Well if that isn't clear, easy and simple, Thanks

Comment: Just when using \begin{filecontents}{mytable.dat}
When I use a \newcounter{magicrownumbers}  --
\newcommand\momentnumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}  -- And use \momentnumber , as an Iteration it will count when ploting another table. Is there a thing to set the command \momentnumber to only be executed when creating the date?

Comment: @SamSammer2 Please ask another question with a _complete_ minimal working example. What is your command for? Counting the rows? There are other ways with `pgfplotstable`.

Comment: I marked it and posted the example with question separate. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442133/filecontents-non-repeating-execution-of-commands