# filecontents non repeating execution of commands

Tags: tables, tex-core, filecontents

As requested by [Merging multiple different tables records. // Splitting table records in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439517/merging-multiple-different-tables-records-splitting-table-records-in-tables/439615?noredirect=1#comment1105851_439615).

I there is a command that I created (a varaint I found here).

```
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\contactnumber{Nr: \stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}
```

Where it is just a simple counter.
When used it just add +1 to the last value.
It is used below.

Now the Issue I have is that the filecontents part. When read multiple times, this command is re-invoked. I want to get the filecontents part to maintain the results of the commands at creation time. To not be able to change every time I use values of the part.

When first running the example you will see the issue more clearly then I an able to explain.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article} % for A4 size paper
\usepackage{array,etoolbox}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xmpincl}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotstableset{
    string type,
    column type=l,
    every head row/.style={
        before row=\toprule,
        after row=\midrule,
    },
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomrule
    },  
}



\begin{document}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\contactnumber{Nr: \stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}

\begin{filecontents}{mytable.dat}
    Moment  Date  Type  subject
    {\contactnumber}     {\today}      RED      Pie
    {\contactnumber}     {\today}      BLUE     Pie         
    {\contactnumber}     {\today}      RED      Apple
    {\contactnumber}     {\today}      BLUE     Apple
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread{mytable.dat}{\mytable}

Whole table:\bigskip

\pgfplotstabletypeset{\mytable}

\bigskip\bigskip Table with only rows with column ``Type''=BLUE:\bigskip

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    row predicate/.code={%
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Type}\of\mytable%
        \ifdefstring{\pgfplotsretval}{BLUE}{}{\pgfplotstableuserowfalse}%
    },
    ]{\mytable}

\bigskip\bigskip Table with only rows with column ``Type''=RED:\bigskip

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    row predicate/.code={%
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Type}\of\mytable%
        \ifdefstring{\pgfplotsretval}{RED}{}{\pgfplotstableuserowfalse}%
    },
    ]{\mytable}


\end{document}
```

Comment: When filecontents is removed. It breaks the example.

Comment: Actually, that was a daft suggestion regardless. But I don't think `filecontents` is a good way to do this, even though I doubt it's the primary problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid putting `{\contactnumber}` in every row and create a new column with the counter with `create col` of `pgfplotstable`.

With `\pgfplotstablesave` you can save the created table to select which rows to show afterward.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article} % for A4 size paper
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotstableset{
    column type=l,
    every head row/.style={
        before row=\toprule,
        after row=\midrule,
    },
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomrule
    },  
    columns/Date/.style={string type},
    columns/Type/.style={string type},
    columns/subject/.style={string type},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{filecontents}{mytable.dat}
        Date      Type     subject
        {\today}  RED      Pie
        {\today}  BLUE     Pie         
        {\today}  RED      Apple
        {\today}  BLUE     Apple
    \end{filecontents}

    Whole table:\bigskip

    \pgfplotstablesave[col sep=comma,
        create on use/Moment/.style={create col/expr={\pgfplotstablerow+1}
        },
        columns={Moment,Date,Type,subject}
        ]{mytable.dat}{mytableout.dat}

    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{mytableout.dat}{\mytable}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        col sep=comma,
        columns={Moment,Date,Type,subject},
        columns/Moment/.style={
            postproc cell content/.append style={
                /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={Nr. }{},
            }
        }
    ]{\mytable}

    \bigskip\bigskip Table with only rows with column ``Type''=BLUE:\bigskip

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        row predicate/.code={%
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Type}\of\mytable%
            \ifdefstring{\pgfplotsretval}{BLUE}{}{\pgfplotstableuserowfalse}%
        },
        col sep=comma,
        columns={Moment,Date,Type,subject},
        columns/Moment/.style={
            postproc cell content/.append style={
                /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={Nr. }{},
            }
        }
    ]{\mytable}

    \bigskip\bigskip Table with only rows with column ``Type''=RED:\bigskip

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        row predicate/.code={%
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Type}\of\mytable%
            \ifdefstring{\pgfplotsretval}{RED}{}{\pgfplotstableuserowfalse}%
        },
        col sep=comma,
        columns={Moment,Date,Type,subject},
        columns/Moment/.style={
            postproc cell content/.append style={
                /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={Nr. }{},
            }
        }
    ]{\mytable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to freeze the number and the date at the time the file is written out, so `filecontents` is not the right tool.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article} % for A4 size paper
\usepackage{array,etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotstableset{
    string type,
    column type=l,
    every head row/.style={
        before row=\toprule,
        after row=\midrule,
    },
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomrule
    },  
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\makedatafile}{mmm}
 {
  \samsammer_makedatafile:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\contactnumber}{}
 {
  \int_eval:n { \l__samsammer_row_int }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \samsammer_today:
 {
  \int_eval:n { \c_sys_year_int } /
  \samsammer_pad:n { \c_sys_month_int } /
  \samsammer_pad:n { \c_sys_day_int }
 }

\iow_new:N \g_samsammer_datafile_stream
\seq_new:N \l__samsammer_datafile_seq
\int_new:N \l__samsammer_row_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \samsammer_makedatafile:nnn
 {
  \group_begin:
  \cs_set_eq:NN \today \samsammer_today:
  \iow_open:Nn \g_samsammer_datafile_stream { #1 }
  \iow_now:Nn \g_samsammer_datafile_stream { #2 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__samsammer_datafile_seq { \\ } { #3 }
  \int_zero:N \l__samsammer_row_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__samsammer_datafile_seq
   {
    \int_incr:N \l__samsammer_row_int
    \iow_now:Nx \g_samsammer_datafile_stream { ##1 }
   }
  \iow_close:N \g_samsammer_datafile_stream
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new:Nn \samsammer_pad:n
 {
  \int_compare:nT { #1 < 10 } { 0 }
  \int_eval:n { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\makedatafile{mytable.dat}
 {Moment  Date  Type  subject}
 {
  {\contactnumber} {\today} RED  Pie \\
  {\contactnumber} {\today} BLUE Pie \\
  {\contactnumber} {\today} RED  Apple \\
  {\contactnumber} {\today} BLUE Apple
 }

\pgfplotstableread{mytable.dat}{\mytable}

Whole table:\bigskip

\pgfplotstabletypeset{\mytable}

\bigskip\bigskip Table with only rows with column ``Type''=BLUE:\bigskip

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    row predicate/.code={%
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Type}\of\mytable%
        \ifdefstring{\pgfplotsretval}{BLUE}{}{\pgfplotstableuserowfalse}%
    },
    ]{\mytable}

\bigskip\bigskip Table with only rows with column ``Type''=RED:\bigskip

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    row predicate/.code={%
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Type}\of\mytable%
        \ifdefstring{\pgfplotsretval}{RED}{}{\pgfplotstableuserowfalse}%
    },
    ]{\mytable}


\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the contents of `mytable.dat`:

```
Moment Date Type subject
{1} {2018/07/19} RED Pie
{2} {2018/07/19} BLUE Pie
{3} {2018/07/19} RED Apple
{4} {2018/07/19} BLUE Apple
```